# Rails: App fails but code runs fine in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The relevant piece of code in the controller is the following:

```
    logger.info("Dumping params")
    logger.info(params)
    logger.info("Dumping initial cost:")
    logger.info(@cost)
    logger.info("entering if statement")
    if params.has_key?("special_edition") && params["special_edition"] == 'yes'
      @cost = @cost + 50000
    end
    logger.info("If we get to here then the first conditional executed correctly")
    if params.has_key?("number_of_lids") && params["number_of_lids"].to_i > 0
      @cost = @cost + (params["number_of_lids"].to_i * 5000)
    end
    logger.info("If we get to here then the second conditional executed correctly")
    logger.info("printing final cost:")
    logger.info(@cost)
```

When I run the app, I get a 500 error. Checking into the log file (test log file), I see the following:

```
Dumping params
{"utf8"=>"✓", "special_edition"=>"yes", "number_of_lids"=>"3", "action"=>"create"}
Dumping initial cost:
350000
entering if statement
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1922ms
```

If I enter the console (rails console), and run this code (values taken from the log file:

```
params = {"utf8"=>"✓", "special_edition"=>"yes", "number_of_lids"=>"3", "action"=>"create"}
@cost = 350000
if params.has_key?("special_edition") && params["special_edition"] == 'yes'
    @cost = @cost + 50000
end
if params.has_key?("number_of_lids") && params["number_of_lids"].to_i > 0
    @cost = @cost + (params["number_of_lids"].to_i * 5000)
end
```

Then I get the correct result for @cost: 415000

Any ideas why I might be getting a 500 error?

## Clarification:

Several responses mentioned that the difference is that the difference is that I'm initializing @cost but not doing it in the controller. The code that's initializing @cost is not included, because it is already initializing properly. I included the piece of code that logs @cost to the log file and I am initializing it in the console using the value I am getting for @cost from the log file (see my code, lines 3 & 4 and then the output from the log file lines 3 & 4)

I tried to use the comment feature, but stackoverlfow is giving me an error message.

## Resolution

It turns out that another module in the app was reading the interget @cost and turning it into a string. This was masked by another bug in the app, so an earlier test failed. Moral of the story: regression testing is essential. Using @cost.to_i fixed the problem

Comment: the only difference i see in your controller code and the rails console is the usage of logger. You are not logging in the case of rails console and also intializing @cost. Have you tried commenting out the logging statements from the controller and checked if you get the 500 ?

Comment: I recommend ditching the logger and using ruby-debug. It'll save your sanity. Read section 3: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: The log output would seem to indicate that @cost is initialized but the line of code that does it simply isn't included in the example, and the fact that there is output to the log indicates that the logging is not causing a problem.  There should be some stack trace or an error message somewhere that would be really useful in troubleshooting this.  Does development.log have anything by chance?

Comment: To Tom L: I do use debug, but the problem with debug is that when I get a 500, I only see the 500 screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```
if params.has_key?(:special_edition) && params[:special_edition] == "yes"
```

if the error persists, just check if the @cost is an integer by assigning a value or with the  to_i method.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in explicit @cost initialization.
Write `@cost = 350000` in start of your controller action.

Comment: please see the edit to my post. @cost is getting initialized in the code

Comment: I donno how to write \@ eithout \ =)